# Starting a python script at boot and loading GUI after that

Tags: python, linux, boot, raspbian, autostart

Can anyone tel me how to start a python script on boot, and then also load the GUI ? I am debian based Raspbian OS.

The reason I want to run the python script on boot is because I need to read key board input from a RFID reader. I am currently using raw_input() to read data from the RFID reader. The 11 character hex value is then compared against  a set of values in a txt file. This raw_input() did not work for me on autostarting python script using crontab and also  using with LXDE autostart.

So, I am thinking to run python script at boot, so that it reads keyboard input. If there are any other ways of reading keyboard input using crontab autostart and LXDE autostart, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Add a bash script to your */etc/init.d* folder running your python program.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /path/to/program/
python2 program.py
```

Then:

```
# update-rc.d startMyPythonProgram.sh defaults 100
```

- defaults: runlevel setting
- 100: priority

Resource: [Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-run-a-command-when-boots-up.html)

Comment: You can do this from tty, ssh, or terminal emulator. What does it have to do with the graphic environment?

Comment: Probably I just misunderstood OP's problem. Nvm.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use bootup option in crontab:

@reboot   python /path/to/pythonfile.py